# need to make string variable which has combination of year and week to datetime format

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, indexing

```
period 

201801

201801

201801

201801

201801
```

it is in string with first four digit is year and last two digit is week, i need to convert to datetime format as year and week and make that variable as index

it tried
`df1['period'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['period'],format='%Y%U')`

its not working

Comment: What specifically is not working?

Comment: It does not show any error for me. Can you paste the error/exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need also the day of the week. You can try in this way:

```
from datetime import datetime
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['201710', 2], ['201715', 3], ['201720', 4]], columns = ['period' ,'val'])
#Add Sunday as day of the week    
df1['period'] = df1['period'].astype(str) + '0'
df1['period'] = df1['period'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%Y%W%w"))
df1.set_index('period', inplace=True)
print (df1)
```

Output:

```
             val
date           
2017-03-12    2
2017-04-16    3
2017-05-21    4
```

Or:

```
df1['period'] = df1['period'].astype(str) + '0'     
df1['period'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['period'], format='%Y%W%w')
df1.set_index('period', inplace=True)
```

And it has the same output

Comment: Yes to this, especially the second option.  You could even combine the two first lines into `df1['period'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['period'].astype(str) + '0', format='%Y%W%w')`, but that might just be an after-effect of too much code golf.

Comment: @mostlyoxygen Yes, of curse I know :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
sdf = pd.DataFrame(['201801','201801','201801','201802','201803'])
sdf['year'] = sdf[0].str[0:4]
sdf['week'] = sdf[0].str[5:7]
sdf['week'] = pd.to_numeric(sdf['week'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'year':sdf['year'], 'week':sdf['week']})
df
```

[image]